# Как разместить объект поверх второго в SDL/C++?

Tags: c++, sdl

Как разместить объект поверх второго в SDL 2.0/C++ ? Хочу написать игру Tic-Tac_Toe что бы на картинку сетки отображались крестик/нолик для начала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала рисуете сетку, потом рисуете крестики/нолики.
Если необходима прозрачность, то можете указать ключевой цвет с помощью SDL_SetColorKey для Surface, или SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod, если работаете с текстурами.